# How do I translate a model inside a module on ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to translate a model on ActiveAdmin.
The model is something like: Module::Model.
I've tried with module_model and module model in the translation yml,
without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a slash between your module name and class name. Like this:

```
"pt-BR":
  activerecord:
    models:
      my_module/my_class:
        one: My Class
        other: My Classes
```

It took me ages to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
activerecord:
  models:
    module/model:
```